# Nuxt: Contidional v-model for checkboxes based on API response

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my nuxt 2 with nuxt 2 composition API I have a list of items that the user can select and then purchase. When the user have previously purchased items these items must show disabled for the user and the checkboxes has to be checked by default. I have a propertie has_purchase within the API response that is true or false if the user has previously purchase the item.

I'm having trouble trying to make the checkboxes checked if the item has been previously purchase. I was thinking is there's any way for the v-model to be dynamic so if has_purchased is true then checkbox is checked but if not unchecked.

This is my single file component:

```
<template>
    <div class="boost">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="page-title">
                {{ $t('upsell.boost.content.title') }}
            </h1>
            <h4 class="page-subtitle">
                {{ $t('upsell.boost.content.description') }}
            </h4>
            <p class="select-instructions">
                {{ $t('upsell.boost.content.select_options_instructions') }}
            </p>
            <LoadingSpinner v-if="isLoading" />
            <ul class="booster-list" v-else>
                <li
                    class="booster"
                    :class="{ 'booster-already-purchased': booster['has_purchased'] }"
                    v-if="isChecked"
                    v-for="(booster, index) in computedBoosters"
                    :style="{
                        background: isChecked[index] ? 'linear-gradient(82.38deg,#f5c33e,#fae36a)' : 'none',
                    }"
                >
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" v-model="isChecked[index]" :disabled="booster['has_purchased']" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="content-title">
                            <img :src="getBoosterIcon(booster['code'])" :alt="booster['name']" class="booster-image" />
                            <h4 class="booster-title">
                                {{ booster['name'] }}
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <p class="content-text">
                            {{ booster['benefits'][0] }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <span class="price-booster">{{ booster['formatted_price'] }} </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div v-if="allPurchased" class="purchased-everything">
                <span>
                    {{ $t('upsell.checkout.purchased_everything_message') }}
                </span>
                <NuxtLink
                    :to="localePath({ name: 'dashboard-castings' })"
                    class="button primary is-medium is-rounded upsell-button"
                    >{{ $t('upsell.checkout.purchased_everything_button_label') }}</NuxtLink
                >
            </div>
            <div class="totals-section" v-else>
                <ul class="selected-boosts">
                    <li v-for="(booster, index) in selectedBoosters" :key="index">
                        <span>{{ booster['name'] }}</span>
                        <span>{{ booster['formatted_price'] }}</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="total">
                    <span class="total-text">{{ $t('upsell.boost.content.total') }}</span>
                    <span class="total-price">{{ calculateTotalPrice }}</span>
                </div>
                <NuxtLink
                    @click.native="handleSelectedBoosters(selectedBoosters)"
                    :to="
                        localePath({
                            name: 'casting-id-boost-checkout',
                            params: { id: $route.params.id },
                        })
                    "
                    class="button primary is-medium is-rounded upsell-button"
                    rounded
                >
                    {{ $t('upsell.boost.content.buy_now_button_label') }}
                </NuxtLink>
                <p class="primary maybe-later-button">
                    <NuxtLink :to="localePath({ name: 'dashboard-castings' })">{{
                        $t('upsell.boost.content.maybe_later_button_label')
                    }}</NuxtLink>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { computed, defineComponent, onMounted, ref, watch } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
    import { isManager } from '~/utils/user'
    import seoTitle from '../../../../utils/seoTitle'
    import useAuth from '~/utils/useAuth'
    import useRouter from '~/utils/useRouter'
    import useStore from '~/utils/useStore'
    import getBoosterIconById from '~/utils/useBoostersIcons'
    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'boost',
        head() {
            return seoTitle(this.$root.$i18n, 'upsell.boost.seo.title', 'upsell.boost.seo.description')
        },
        setup(_, context) {
            const { router, route } = useRouter(context)
            const {
                actions: { fetch: fetchBoosters, setSelectedBoosters: setSelectedBoosters },
                state: boostersState,
            } = useStore(context, 'boosters')
            const auth = useAuth(context)
            const boostersData = ref<BoostData | null>(boostersState.boostersData)
            const id = route.value.params.id
            const isLoading = ref(true)
            const paymentType = 'boost'
            const handleSelectedBoosters = (selectedBoosters: SelectedBooster[]) => {
                setSelectedBoosters(selectedBoosters)
            }
            const isChecked = ref<boolean[]>(boostersState.boostersIcons.map(() => false))
            const getBoosterDetails = async () => {
                isLoading.value = true
                try {
                    await fetchBoosters({ context, id, paymentType })
                } catch (error: any) {
                    if (!auth.loggedIn || !isManager(auth.user)) {
                        router.push(`/`)
                    }
                } finally {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        isLoading.value = false
                    }, 100)
                }
            }
            onMounted(() => {
                getBoosterDetails()
            })
            const getBoosterIcon = (id: string): string => {
                return getBoosterIconById(context, id)
            }
            watch(
                () => boostersState.boostersData,
                (newBoostersData) => {
                    boostersData.value = newBoostersData
                },
                { deep: true }
            )
            const allPurchased = computed(() => {
                if (computedBoosters.value) {
                    return computedBoosters.value.every((booster) => booster.has_purchased)
                }
                return false
            })
            const computedBoosters = computed<UpsellItem[] | null>(() => {
                if (boostersData.value) {
                    return Object.values(boostersData.value) as UpsellItem[] | null
                } else {
                    return []
                }
            })
            const selectedBoosters = computed(() => {
                const selected: any[] = []
                isChecked.value.forEach((isSelected, index) => {
                    if (isSelected && computedBoosters.value) {
                        const booster = computedBoosters.value[index]
                        selected.push({ ...booster })
                    }
                })
                return selected
            })
            const calculateTotalPrice = computed(() => {
                let totalPrice = 0
                isChecked.value.forEach((isSelected, index) => {
                    if (isSelected && computedBoosters.value) {
                        const booster = computedBoosters.value[index]
                        totalPrice += parseFloat(booster.price)
                    }
                })
                const currencySymbol =
                    computedBoosters.value && computedBoosters.value.length > 0
                        ? computedBoosters.value[0].currency_symbol
                        : ''
                if (currencySymbol === '€' || currencySymbol === '$') {
                    return totalPrice.toFixed(2) + currencySymbol
                } else {
                    return currencySymbol + totalPrice.toFixed(2)
                }
            })
            return {
                allPurchased,
                boostersData,
                calculateTotalPrice,
                computedBoosters,
                getBoosterDetails,
                getBoosterIcon,
                handleSelectedBoosters,
                isChecked,
                isLoading,
                selectedBoosters,
            }
        },
    })
</script>
```

Importan parts of the code in order to find a solution to this is:

Checkboxes are disable if booster['has_purchased'] and the v-model here is the problem because they checkboxes are disabled and with the proper styles when they are purchased but the checkboxes are not checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="isChecked[index]" :disabled="booster['has_purchased']" />
```

Then my original binding (I know that this is not caring about the booster['has_purchased'] but have try diff. ways and can't get it to work:

```
const isChecked = ref<boolean[]>(boostersState.boostersIcons.map(() => false))
```

boostersState.boostersIcons is coming from a store and this is the shape:

```
boostersIcons: [
    {
        id: 'boost-launcher',
        icon: require('~/assets/images/upsell/boost/icons/launcher-icon.svg'),
        has_purchased: true,
    },
    {
        id: 'boost-outstanding',
        icon: require('~/assets/images/upsell/boost/icons/outstanding-icon.svg'),
        has_purchased: false,
    },
    {
        id: 'boost-urgent',
        icon: require('~/assets/images/upsell/boost/icons/urgent-icon.svg'),
        has_purchased: false,
    },
    {
        id: 'boost-agent-assistance',
        has_purchased: false,
        icon: require('~/assets/images/upsell/boost/icons/support.svg'),
        has_purchased: false,
    },
    {
        id: 'boost-improve-your-casting',
        icon: require('~/assets/images/upsell/boost/icons/improve-icon.svg'),
        has_purchased: false,
    },
]
```

And finally for context this is the api response transformed into a computed property within the component:

```
[{
    "code": "boost-launcher",
    "name": "Launcher",
    "price": "12",
    "formatted_price": "£12",
    "currency_symbol": "£",
    "currency_iso": "GBP",
    "has_purchased": false,
    "benefits": ["Un 50% más modelos verán tu casting, por lo que conseguirás más candidatos"]
}, {
    "code": "boost-outstanding",
    "name": "Destacado",
    "price": "12",
    "formatted_price": "£12",
    "currency_symbol": "£",
    "currency_iso": "GBP",
    "has_purchased": false,
    "benefits": ["Recibirá candidatos de mayor calidad que se ajustan a tu brief"]
}, {
    "code": "boost-urgent",
    "name": "Urgente",
    "price": "19",
    "formatted_price": "£19",
    "currency_symbol": "£",
    "currency_iso": "GBP",
    "has_purchased": false,
    "benefits": ["Recibe una respuesta más rápida a tu casting, ya que el número de inscritos se disparará en tan sólo 24 horas"]
}, {
    "code": "boost-agent-assistance",
    "name": "Asistencia de un agente",
    "price": "29",
    "formatted_price": "£29",
    "currency_symbol": "£",
    "currency_iso": "GBP",
    "has_purchased": false,
    "benefits": ["Nuestro equipo te ayudará a conseguir los mejores candidatos para tu proyecto"]
}, {
    "code": "boost-improve-your-casting",
    "name": "Mejora tu casting",
    "price": "39",
    "formatted_price": "£39",
    "currency_symbol": "£",
    "currency_iso": "GBP",
    "has_purchased": false,
    "benefits": ["Haz que tu casting destaque con la ayuda de nuestro equipo de redactores y editores de imágenes"]
}]
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a more general problem in which setting the value of a checkbox does nothing if it's disabled

Comment: Don't really know if I'm getting what you are saying @SIGSTACKFAULT. It's basically a UX concern to show already purchased products I don't really need to make any sort of mutation or setter.

Comment: (reads the actual answer) idk what i meant either, i was very tired at the time

Comment: yeah better not to answer for the sake of typing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to watch the state in the store for changes first, then evaluate the typeof data and the existence of the state coming from the store and then assign a new array of elements based on the "on_purchased" property so the checkboxes change "checked" state based on that.

```
    watch(
        () => boostersState.boostersData,
        (newBoostersData) => {
            boostersData.value = newBoostersData
            if (newBoostersData && typeof newBoostersData === 'object') {
                isChecked.value = Object.values(newBoostersData).map((booster: any) => booster['has_purchased'])
            }
        },
        { deep: true }
    )
```